# Javascript ADO command object records affected

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, ado

I want to change an existing JavaScript ADODB.command.Execute() to return the number of records affected by the command.  Here is my initial attempt:

```
var lngRecs = 0; 
cmdTemp.Execute(lngRecs, , );
```

This code did not get interpreted/compiled successfully.  I am having trouble finding JavaScript examples using the Records Affected property for the ADO command object.  Also, the command is text SQL currently.  I am looking to change it to use a stored procedure.  A previous post states that the records affected property may be returned in a record set.  I would prefer not working with a recordset.

Comment: You should be passing `adExecuteNoRecords | adCmdText` in the second parameter if you aren't expecting a recordset back.

Comment: I changed to code to:

Comment: I changed to code to: DataConn.Execute(str, lngRecs, 1);  The lngRecs variable is zero.  A record did get inserted however.  I get the same results with cmdTemp.Execute(str, lngRecs, 1); My problem is that the table is not defined with an identity column otherwise, I would return the new identity value.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `adExecuteNoRecords | adCmdText` would be 129 I think rather than 1.

Comment: I am going to try using a stored procedure and use an output parameter to return the number of rows affected.